# Getting location from Twitter profile in R

Tags: r, twitter

I need to be able to get the location of the user, the geocodes are returning NA for searchTwitter(). How do I get the the profile and store the location of the user with only the user_name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install and make use of the `R` Twitter package:

```
install.packages("twitteR")

# get user object for Kim Kardashian
user <- getUser("KimKardashian")
# now you know where Kim Kardashian lives
print(user$location)
```

If you had a data frame called `users_df` which also had a column `username`, you could use the following code to obtain the locations for all users:

```
getLocation <- function(x) {
    y <- getUser(x)
    location <- y$location
    return location
}

users_df$username
locations <- sapply(users_df$username, function(x) getLocation(x))
```

By the way, the `getUser` call will only succeed if the profile you are trying to access is public.  Don't have a cow if you can't find out where Kim Kardashian lives.

Comment: I am using windows and I got "Error in tw_from_response(out, ...) : 
  unused argument (cainfo = "cacert.pem")"

Comment: Can you try removing the `cainfo` parameter from the call to `getUser`?

Comment: ok that worked! (I can't follow basic directions) now can I use one of the apply's so it returns the location of every user in my data frame?